# html 5 video tag is not playing first time clicked in android using JavaScript on browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, video, browser

I am using an html 5 page 
with a video tag and a dynamic source .
any time the user click on the page I assign the source to the video 
and play it

```
<video ></video>

$(div).click(function()
{
$('video').src('filename.mp4');
$('video').get(0).load();
$('video').get(0).play();
});
```

At the first click nothing happens and at the 2 time the video is playing

What am I missing ??

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use improperly the jQuery selector for clicking on the `div` element. The code should be (mark the quotes):

```
$("div").click(function() {
$('video').src('filename.mp4');
$('video').get(0).load();
$('video').get(0).play();
});
```

However, it is always better not to use general selector (this will be applied to all `div` elements), but give your `div`, which you use for action triggering a CSS class or ID, for example like this:

```
<div id="my-div-id">Click to play</div>
<video id="my-video-id"> </video>
<script>
$("div#my-div-id").click(function() {
$('video#my-video-id').src('filename.mp4');
$('video#my-video-id').get(0).load();
$('video').get(0).play();
});
</script>
```

Comment: bodi0 thanks but not the click attach event is my problem but the not playing the first time its being click